# How to download binary/video files from html5 Storage or JQuery using Local Storage

Tags: jquery, html, cookies, storage, local-storage

I have been reading so much articles about JQuery, html5 LocalStorage but I could not get what I want yet.

This is my doubt: I have some url that are part of a video (the format does not matter) and I would like to download those files as cookies or as temporally files, it does not matter if they are save as binary file, or movie file.

I know that is possible to download string and save it as cookies. But, how can I do this?

I have also been looking at JQuery lib, but I could not do it yet.

Any help would be appreciate.

My best regards,
Antonio

Comment: When I say "How can I do this" I mean the video/binaries, the string I already know how to do that.

Comment: Please, I really need this... any help would be awesome

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really old but I was looking up the answer to this question myself and found this out:

HTML5 storage does not allow you to store binary data. So if you wanted to store a video you would need to encode the entire video into Base64 and then store it as text.